# What is purpose of CURL_UPLOAD option in CURL

Tags: php, curl

if upload file , i can use `$data = array('file' => '@/home/user/test.png');`
then what is purpose of CURL_UPLOAD option ?

Answer (score 1):

Uploading a file to a remote server.

Answer (score 0):

curl supports many different ways of uploading, using a large amount of different protocols.

This array-approach shown above is only used for doing HTTP multipart formposts. If you for example rather want a HTTP PUT, or upload with FTP, FTPS or SFTP etc, that's the option for you...